# Service that shows most popular queries/keywords related to a specific topic X?

Tags: webapp-rec, google-search, search, webservice

I know *Google Trends/Zeitgeist*. But what I'm looking for is a service where you can enter, for example "Politics", and then the service gives out the most popular queries containing "Politics"-keyword in the query, so I can see the other keywords people are using in combination with it.

Comment: @Barry Why was this question closed as "not constructive"? I don't see anything "off-topic" about it.

Comment: @AndersonGreen See this [meta post](http://meta.webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/1000) on the subject. Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [**Google Insights for Search (Beta)**](http://www.google.com/insights/search/#).

Just enter your search term(s) in the search box and hit Enter. You will see the **top searchs** and **rising searches** about your search term listed below.

[image: img01]
[image]

Comment: Great, thanks. If you download the .csv file on top you get some more search terms than the listed ones.

Comment: The link to Google Insights for Search now redirects to the Google Trends homepage. I wonder if this service is still available anywhere.

Answer (score 2):

You can use Google's autocomplete, if you type in a keyword it gives you a few suggestions which seem to be pulled of the most popular query (although surely heavily filtered). You can also try to add a space before you word *after* you typed it in to get a few new results.

[image: Google example]

Comment: +1 thanks, didn't thought of this, tested it a bit. Unfortunately people seem not to use more than 3 search words, then auto-completion mostly stops. I still would prefer a bit more detailed statistical data.